# Texting and emailing audio recordings size issues

Tags: ios, audio

For my app, I'm trying to implement a share feature that allows users to send audio recordings (m4a) via text or email.  However, audio files that exceed 2.5-3 mins fail to send because they're beyond the size limit.  Whats the best way around this?  I noticed on the iphone audio recorder, sending audio files 5+ mins long is no issue.  What gives?

My fall back options are iCloud and dropbox, but I want to see if text and email are even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Size limits for emails depend on the provider so it is something that's very user dependent. I'm not sure how texts (MMS) work but they're probably also dependent on the service provider.
Maybe you could you add the ability to reduce the quality (thus reducing the size of the file) or splitting the file into multiple pieces before sending it. In any case, as you said, cloud services are probably your best option for large audio files.